# Rabbitmq - configuration backup to script

Tags: rabbitmq, command-line-interface

I would like to generate a scritpt able to clone a rabbitmqconf (for exchange, vhost, queue, binding) from an existing conf to a bash script which can be then run on another server (test / dev / preprod).
By example using rabbitmqctl or rabbitmqadmin and get the command done to create queue, something like

```
rabbitmqadmin -u xxx -p xxx declare queue --vhost=logstash name=drupalmysql durable=false
```

Of course I would need to add user/password myself.

I'm already using

```
/usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin export -u xxx -p xxx  home/arte/rabbitmq.config
```

But it generates a whole json file which I can use as a backup.

So ... To the point :) Is  it possible to get command internally used in gui to create a bash file with it inside ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "command internally used in gui", but you can use [the rest API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html) to create (or whatever) all entities. Basically write a script with curl, postman etc.

AFAIK rabbitmq.config doesn't contain info about existing queues etc.